# What is the correct time complexity?

Tags: java, arrays, big-o

I am writing an algorithm to convert a n*n matrix into a single array.

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I am confused if what I have done is O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(n<sup>3</sup>):

```
public int[] mergeMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int[] array : matrix) {
        for (int i : array) {
            tempList.add(i);
        }
    }
    int totalLength = tempList.size();
    int[] mergedArray = new int[totalLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
        mergedArray[i] = tempList.get(i);
    }
    return mergedArray;
}
```

Would it be O(n<sup>2</sup>) because that is the longest worst case of the algorithms processes, or is it O(n<sup>3</sup>) because O(n) + O(n<sup>2</sup>) = O(n<sup>3</sup>)?

Comment: It's `O(m*n)`. i.e. `O(numItemsInMatrix)`. P.S since when is `a^x + a^y = a^(x+y)`? `2^10 + 2^10 = 2^20`?

Comment: FYI you can completely get rid of the second loop with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-

Comment: Ah so using a nested for loop doesn't automatically make it O(n^2)? It's more to do with with the data structure you iterate over?

Comment: Of course not - it could make it `O(n lg n)`, for example. A single loop could be `O(n^2)`. You need to look at the loops, not just count them.

Comment: Also, O(n) + O(n^2) ≠ O(n^3). O(n) + O(n^2) = O(n^2). Big-O is the worst case for_very large n_. As _n_ gets larger, O(n^2) dominates, meaning that O(n) doesn't contribute a large enough value that would make a difference compared to O(n^2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime complexity of this is O(nm), where `n` is the number of rows and `m` is the number of columns in your matrix.

The reason for this:

- You perform exactly one operation for *each* element in your matrix total, which is bound by the number of rows and columns you have.

In the context of `n = m`, then this would be O(n*n) or O(n<sup>2</sup>), but *only* then.

The number of loops doesn't really matter here since you could be doing incredibly *fancy* iteration with it.  Be sure to look at the operations you're actually performing in the loop; since they're linear, I would expect the runtime to be a linear runtime times a linear runtime because of the nested nature.

Comment: So this would be O(n^2) because I am working with a n*n matrix yes?

Comment: @PumpkinBreath: Yes, because you explicitly have `n = 3` and `m = 3`.

Comment: So with that being the case would you say this is an O(n^2) algorithm overall? I am struggling to understand how these things add up

Comment: **No.**  It is *not* an O(n^2) algorithm.  It is very explicitly an O(n*m) algorithm.  Law of exponents dictates that n * n = n^2 which is why this matters in an n = m context.

Comment: @PumpkinBreath it's fundamentally an `O(e)` algorithm where `e` is the number of elements in the input matrix. Given that arrays in Java can be jagged no more can be said than that. Everything else makes assumptions about the input.

Comment: Assuming a non jagged array, it can be O(n^2) only if one dimension is dependent on the other. Otherwise it is O(nm).